# how to open mutliple pdf pages in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pdf, photo-editing, photoshop-scripting

I am actually trying to save all pages in the pdf as a png image but here i can't open all pages in one time.
i have [read here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/extract-images-pdf-files-save-windows/) for how to open pdf pages 
I have to open one by one and then i am saving it as png image. this is taking long time to finish.

> Is there any shortcut to open mutliple pdf pages in photoshop and save
>   as a image

Answer (score 6):

You could do it in Acrobat with Export > Image > PNG

In Photoshop it's more complex.
When opening a PDF you can select all pages by holding shift. That way all pages open and the opened documents are named by page number.

Exporting is a different thing though.
You could start with the Automate > Batch and choose all open files as source, and using an Action you recorded (e.g. Save as PNG). The downside is that Photoshop will promt you to save all open files as PSD as well which makes the process a lot less elegant.

Comment: where is the Export option in Acrobat

Comment: You don't need Acrobat Pro for this, just Acrobat. Reader won't do it though.

Answer (score 0):

To save multiple PSD files as PNG, create an 'Action' to automate the process:

**Steps:**

1. Create an 'Action' with required steps, in your case save as 'png'
   (Window > Action or Alt + F9).
2. Place all PSDs in a folder.
3. Create a target folder for PNGs.
4. Use batch processing to apply previously created 'Action' on all
   PSDs.(File > Automate > Batch)

You can follow a tutorial [here](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/photoshop-tutorial-1-click-photo-editing-with-action/)

Answer (score 0):

File Drag to Photoshop then you can select pages by using SHIFT key

Note: Do not open by file through File->Open

Answer (score -2):

i like to use animate > batch > save to psd presentation.

Comment: I cannot find an `Animate` menu in Photoshop.

Comment: Is it "Automate" !?